# Does FCM support multilingual - Firebase Push Notification?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app, multilingual, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using Ionic latest to develop Hybrid app. I have integrated FCM with Ionic.

I am looking for Multilingual support in FCM (Android and iOS). 
Does FCM support for Chinese, Bahasa languages?

If you have used FCM with Chinese, Bahasa languages, please advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FCM supports subscribing to a topic.

You can set that topic to be the language.

- en
- de

[image: de_news]